# ¿Cómo recurro a un dato de un fichero binario para editarlo? Python

Tags: python, archivo

Este sería el enunciado del ejercicio:

[image]

Anteriormente ya he realizado la opción principal del programa que añade nuevos abonados pero no se como puedo obtener el número de abonado para cambiar su facturación.

```
def opc1():
    print("-Alta de Factura-")
    num_abo = int(input("Introduzca el número de abonado: "))
    print("Introduzca nombre del cliente: ", end="")
    nombre = input()
    valor_fact = float(input("Indique el valor de la factura: "))
    abonado = {"num_abo": num_abo, "nombre": nombre, "valor_fact": valor_fact}
    listAbonado = []
    listAbonado.append(abonado)
    f = open("abonado.dat", "wb")
    pickle.dump(listAbonado, f)
    f.close()
    print("Abonado registrado con éxito\n\n")

def opc2():
    print("Modificación de Factura")
    int(input("Intruduzca el número de abonado para cambiar su factura: "))
    with open("abonado.dat", "rb+") as f:
        for a in f:
            if a == num_abo:
```

¿¿¿Una ayudita???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una posible solución es usar la función [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) lo que nos permite iterar sobre los datos cargados del fichero y hacer la comprobación para encontrar el abono solicitado.

Ejemplo:

```
def opc2():
    print("Modificación de Factura")
    num_abo_input = int(input("Intruduzca el número de abonado para cambiar su factura: "))
    abonos = None  # Guardamos aqui los datos cargados desde el fichero
    with open("abonado.dat", "rb+") as f:
        # Cargar(transformar) los datos
        abonos = pickle.load(f)  
        # Simplemente  estamos recorriendo la lista abonos
        # y por cada uno comprueba si el num_abo es igual que el solicitado.
        # En caso de que no exista devuelve None como valor por defecto
        abono = next((abono for abono in abonos if abono.get('num_abo') == num_abo_input), None)
        if not abono:
            print(f"El abono {num_abo_input} no se ha encontrado")
        else:
            # Aqui tenemos el abono
            print(abono)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!